# access session from different port in same IP NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, nginx

I have 2 web application in same IP and different port:

- app1 = (site.com) -> 66.88.66.88:5000
- app2 = (login.site.com) -> 66.88.66.88:5001

I`m using Nginx and set 2 proxy for these 2 application. The users have to login in to app1 and system will set a session for logged in user. after that system will redirect user to app2 and I need access to logged in user session in appp2.
I store my session in mongodb in same collecton that both apps has access to that.

**My problem** is I can`t have access to loggedin user session in app2.

This is my session settings:

app1:

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(config.dbhost, function(err){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   } else {
       console.log('connected to the database successfuly.');
   }
});

/* Session config */
var expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 7 days
app.use(session({
   secret: config.secureHasherKey ,
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   cookie: {
       secure: false,
       httpOnly: true,
       domain: 'site.com',
       path: '/', 
       expires: expiryDate
   },
   store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: connection })
}));
```

app2:

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(config.dbhost, function(err){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   } else {
       console.log('connected to the database successfuly.');
   }
});

/* Session config */
var expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 7 days
app.use(session({
   secret: config.secureHasherKey ,
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   cookie: {
       secure: false,
       httpOnly: true,
       domain: 'login.site.com',
       path: '/', 
       expires: expiryDate
   },
   store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: connection })
}));
```

And this is my CORS settings:

```
app.all("*", function (req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, 
   Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
   return next();
 });
```

How can I find the problem?

Comment: Start by checking if a (proper) cookie gets set by `app1`, and if that cookie is being sent in the request to `app2`. FWIW, don't use `expires`, use `maxAge`. See [the fine manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#cookieexpires).

Comment: `login.site.com` is an subdomain `site.com` . take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix `app1` sets a cookie for the entire domain `site.com`.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix I checked that link but I still don`t know how can I solve my problem? My session saved in mongo and after I refresh the page, system saved some new empty session  (by each refresh !!!)  my sessions aren`t stable !!

Comment: I appended my CORS settings if you need

Comment: @robertklep I need help, Could you help me? The problem now is just I can't read sessions in app2